# Describe Temp table columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have this script:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (Id int)

ALTER TABLE #TempTable ADD [IdKey] INT 
ALTER TABLE #TempTable ADD [ProviderName] NVARCHAR(100)

SELECT * 
FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TempTable');
```

I need to read the columns of this temp table and create another temp table based on the previous one.
Why when I do the select of tempdb.sys.columns, the ProviderName length is 200 instead of 100?

Comment: I found it it's because of the NVARCHAR but I need the NVARCHAR

Comment: Nvarchar allocates double the amount of length to hold Unicode info

Comment: The number is still the maximum number of characters not the data length

Comment: I got it but how I can get the value 100 using that structure?

Comment: My point is to create another temp table based on the first one so I need to read the columns from #TempTable and alter another table, because #TempTable has a column nvarchar, I need to reproduce the same column nvarchar with the same size 100

Comment: I found a solution using SELECT * FROM [tempdb].[sys].[dm_exec_describe_first_result_set] (N'SELECT Id, [IdKey], [ProviderName] FROM #temptable', null, 0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this will solve the issue:

SELECT * FROM [tempdb].[sys].[dm_exec_describe_first_result_set] (N'SELECT Id, [IdKey], [ProviderName] FROM #temptable', null, 0);

Answer (score 1):

With this simple query it's possible to copy the temp table structure:

```
SELECT *
INTO #NewTempTable
FROM #TempTable
WHERE 1 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Clone Temporary Table Structure to New Physical Table in SQL Server**

[image]

we will see how to Clone Temporary Table Structure to New Physical Table in SQL Server.This is applicable for both Azure SQL db and on-premises.

***Demo SQL Script***

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempTable;

SELECT 1 AS ID,'Arul' AS Names
INTO
#TempTable;

SELECT * FROM #TempTable;
```

***METHOD 1***

```
SELECT * INTO TempTable1 FROM #TempTable WHERE 1=0;

EXEC SP_HELP TempTable1;
```

[image]

***METHOD 2***

```
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO TempTable1 FROM #TempTable;

EXEC SP_HELP TempTable1;
```

[image]